# Retrieve list of all Azure locations and services?

Tags: azure, azure-management-api

Does anyone know if there are any generic Azure API's for retrieving a list of all their locations and services, independent of a specific subscription?

Answer (score 1):

[**Get-AzureRmLocation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermlocation?view=azurermps-4.4.0) => Gets all locations and the supported resource providers for each location.

Resource Manager is supported in all regions, but the resources you deploy might not be supported in all regions. In addition, there may be limitations on your subscription that prevent you from using some regions that support the resource.

**((Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.AnyService).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq AnyService).Locations**

**Note:** Replace AnyService with ResourceProvider.

The API version corresponds to a version of REST API operations that are released by the resource provider.

For more details, refer "[**Resource providers and types**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services)".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you help!  We ended up having to scrape the Azure status page.  There were no easy mappings from Get-AzureRmLocation to their 4 layer deep status page (zones, regions, category, services).